# Eclipse Mars 1.0 Build Path Missing From Properties Menu

Tags: eclipse

I have just reinstalled my OS and made a clean install of Eclipse.

I want to import my previous projects made on a previous version of Eclipse and that is no problem. However when I try to run it then it says: "The selection cannot be run on any server".

I read around I need to go into Properties => Build Path and do something there.

Only problem is my Properties menu does not have a Build Path option. I have searched around Eclipse for a long time now to find Build Path but stil no luck.

Does anyone now where og why my Build Path is no where to be found?

Comment: Which of the Eclipse Mars downloads did you install? Some of them don't do Java development so you need to get the correct one.

Comment: I need it for web development.

Comment: The description for that Eclipse version says html, css and javascript which is what i am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Chance i found the solution myself.

I originally installed the Eclipse Php Mars version of Eclipse which i still can't get to work. But install the Eclipse Jee Mars (Java EE IDE) version instead solves the problem.

First time you run the code though you might have to run it through the main menu in the top and not by the convenient Run icon botton.

I have no clue why this is but now i can continue my work.